# Regex problem: find if error stack has "anonymous" with line and column

Tags: javascript, regex

Imagine there is the JavaScript error like:

```
ReferenceError: f is not defined\n    at eval (eval at CodeR._this.javascriptRun 
(http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:29635:20), <anonymous>:4:2)\n  
at CodeR._this.javascriptRun (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:29635:20)\n 
at http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:29554:15\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    
at CodeR._this.evaluateCode (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:29553:25)\n    
at callCallback (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:102449:12)\n    at 
commitUpdateEffects (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:102487:7)\n    at 
commitUpdateQueue (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:102475:3)\n    at 
commitLifeCycles (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:110741:11)\n    at 
commitLayoutEffects (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:113941:7)
```

How to check it and if it has a part like `<anonymous>:line:col` and catch them.

For this example, it would be 4 and 2.

Regex for Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple regex ought to do

```js
var error = document.querySelector("#error").innerHTML;

// find the text with `<anonymous>:(find and place in result[1] one or more digit):(place number in result[2])`
var result = /<anonymous>:(\d+):(\d+)/.exec(error);

if (result && result[2]) {
  console.log(result[1], result[2]);
} else {
  console.log("not found");
}
```

```html
<div id="error">
  ReferenceError: f is not defined\n at eval (eval at CodeR._this.javascriptRun (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:29635:20),
  <anonymous>:4:2)\n at CodeR._this.javascriptRun (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:29635:20)\n at http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:29554:15\n at new Promise (
    <anonymous>)\n at CodeR._this.evaluateCode (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:29553:25)\n at callCallback (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:102449:12)\n at commitUpdateEffects (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:102487:7)\n
      at commitUpdateQueue (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:102475:3)\n at commitLifeCycles (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:110741:11)\n at commitLayoutEffects (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/dist/a.bundle.js:113941:7)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, wizard, it's working like a charm :))